# How to make sure a string of pure whitespace is invalid with a succinct code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am making a section with TextFields and Button("Continue") and then use **.disable(isValidAddress)** modifier to a whole section to disable the button. The code works well, but I am seeking any solution to make it more succinct with no need to write .hasPrefix() or .hasSuffix() to all parameters one by one.

```
var isValidAddress: Bool {
    if name.hasPrefix(" ") || street.hasPrefix(" ") || city.hasPrefix(" ") || country.hasPrefix(" ") {
        return false
    } else if name.hasSuffix(" ") || street.hasSuffix(" ") || city.hasSuffix(" ") || country.hasSuffix(" ") {
        return false
    }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them to an array and trim white space and check if empty in a loop

```
func isValidAddress() -> Bool {
    for field in [name, street, city, country] {
        if field.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty { return false }
    }
    return true 
}
```

I used a function here but a computed property works just as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
var isValidAddress: Bool {
[street, name, city, etc..].reduce(true, { result, text in
    if text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
        return false
    } else {
        return result
    }
})
```

}

Comment: So the final code will be this:

`var isValidAddress: Bool {`
  `!name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty`
  `!street.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty`
  `!city.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty`
  `!country.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty`
`}`

Is it possible to avoid these repeating writings? I mean what if there are a 20 TextFields, so it should be 20 lines of code?

Comment: I changed it to use another option, but @JoakimDanielson's answer is better, it uses an early return and reads much nicer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind moving some complexity into extensions, you can tidy up the call site.  This makes it more readable, and less error prone - you can easily add in another field without mistakes for example.

```
 extension String {
    func hasPrefixOrSuffix(_ s: String) -> Bool {
        hasPrefix(s) || hasSuffix(s)
    }

    var noSpacesAtEnds: Bool {
        !hasPrefixOrSuffix(" ")
    }
}

let isValid = [name, street, city, country]
    .allSatisfy(\.noSpacesAtEnds)
```

If you do mean none of them are "all whitespace strings" then:

```
extension String {
    var isNotAllWhitespace: Bool {
        !trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty
    }
}

let isValid = [name, street, city, country]
    .allSatisfy(\.isNotAllWhitespace)
```

One benefit of having named functions for these things is you can test the pieces, so you can write a test to ensure that `isNotAllWhitespace` works the way you expect.  You couldn't if the logic like `name.hasPrefix(" ") || street.hasPrefix(" ")` is mixed in with your isValidAddress function.

Comment: The first part of your answer is not very flexible, what about multiple spaces or a tab or a combination of them? And what would an empty string return?

Comment: Indeed, this represents how you might write the exact same functionality as the code in the original question more succinctly